# Discord Bot get ID of Slash Command

Tags: node.js, json, axios, discord.js

I am having issues trying to get the ID of my Slash Commands in Discord

But I keep getting the same error over and over

```
ReferenceError: applicationId is not defined
```

Please tell me what I am doing wrong here

MY CODE:

```
const axios = require('axios');

const applicationId = 'APPLICATION_ID'; // Replace with your application ID
const guildId = 'GUILD_ID'; // Replace with your guild ID
const commandName = 'COMMAND_NAME'; // Replace with the name of the command

const headers = {
  Authorization: `Bot YOUR_BOT_TOKEN`,
  'Content-Type': 'application/json'
};

axios.get(`https://discord.com/api/v9/applications/${applicationId}/guilds/${guildId}/commands`, { headers })
  .then(response => {
    const command = response.data.find(cmd => cmd.name === commandName);
    if (command) {
      console.log(`ID of ${commandName}: ${command.id}`);
    } else {
      console.log(`Command "${commandName}" not found`);
    }
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.error(error);
  });
```

*Update 06-05-23 8:10 New Error:*

**Do not worry about the BOT Token in this file it already has been reset**

[Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/TnZJM2KN)